# Adjective for one meaning of "argument"

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

I am searching for a word, an adjectival form of the word "argument" in its sense as: "a statement or series of statements for or against something." The word "argumentative" does not work. I am looking for an adjective that can replace "opinion" in the following sentence: "It demonstrates most of the features of opinion writing and ... " I am not at liberty to rephrase the sentence, but a different adjective -- if there is one more precise than "opinion" -- could be used. Would anyone recommend using the word "argument" as an adjective?

Comment: Adjectives which supplant the subjective *argument* with an *objective* synonym are logical, deductive and reasoned. None of these have a strong relationship to the phrase **"___ writing"**. Opinion writing to my mind would mean either editorializing, as in journalism, or a justice of the court writing an interpretation of the law. This latter is most peculiar, because it is definitely an opinion, but one that becomes fact upon publication (until overturned or re-legislated). What is the context is your sentence?

Answer (score 5):

Although the term *argumentative* can be used here, the more common term for this type of work is *discursive writing*. Here's a definition the adjective *discursive* from [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discursive):

> > 1 a :  moving from topic to topic without order :  rambling
> >
> > 1 b :  proceeding coherently from topic to topic
>
> 2
>   :  marked by analytical reasoning

Note that this usage derives from the last two definitions, not the first!!!

Here's an example taken from the Cambridge University website for IELTS teaching:

- The texts may be written in different styles, for example, narrative, descriptive or discursive/argumentative.

Answer (score 3):

The adjective **argumentatious** is less influenced by the far more common sense of *argumentative*. It is also far less common, but is given by say [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/argumentatious).

I'd be tempted to use the compound **argument-based**. Check how it is used in [this article](http://dspace.nwu.ac.za/handle/10394/10793) say by the North-West University.

Answer (score 2):

It is correct to use [*argumentative*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/argumentative) writing in your example. Here *argumentative* means using reasoning.